# Best way to develop E-commerence website in asp.net for small scale business

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dotnetnuke

I have to develop e-commerence web portal, i am confused whether to use asp.net web form, dotnetnuke or asp.net mvc ?
I dont have experience with dornetnuke so is it good to develop such portal?
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to StackOverFlow, I'll answer your question. However, please do not ask opinion based question anymore.

**DotNetNuke** is not a technology instead it is a CMS which is written in ASP.Net Web Form.

On the other hand, **Orchard and Umbraco** are written in ASP.Net MVC.

If you are new to ASP.Net shopping cart, you might want to read [Beginning ASP.NET E-Commerce in C#: From Novice to Professional (Expert's Voice in .NET)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210745) in which you will be creating a small shopping cart site using PayPal.

If you are primarily look for an open source shopping cart, **nopCommerce** (written in MVC) is one of the best. But it'll take few days to few weeks to understand the concept depending on your experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to all the 3 technologies better take up MVC. Well, web forms are very easy.